# Unable to overwrite bootstrap with external css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I recently started a coding bootcamp and we are learning about bootstrap.  A lot of my friends prefer to stay away from bootstrap for other reasons, but we are learning it in class so no choice. Anyway, I've tried many things. I've tried adding a new class to the element I'm trying to style, I've tried to be specific like `div > p .lead`, and quite a few other ideas, all followed by the `!important` text. I am starting to think perhaps maybe my external stylesheet isn't being linked properly. I've quadruple checked the file locations and tried changing things to see if that would help, still no dice. I've tried reaching out to some of my friends for help as well, but most of them are already at work and can't help me at the moment, so that brings me here!

My HTML and CSS code. I know the CSS is pretty plain, this is just for testing purposes, trying to find out how to overwrite the html. I greatly appreciate your time for looking at this.

On a side note, a lot of my classmates make fun of how I space out my coding. If you guys think this is an issue, speak up! I want to know so I don't get locked into one way of doing things, and have time to adjust my muscle memory before it sets in and becomes tough to change! Thank you

```css
.jumbotron h1
{
    background-image: url(/img/pizza.png) !important;
}
title
{
    font-family: cursive !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html 
    lang="en"
>
<head>
<link 
    rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"
>
<link 
    rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css"
    href="/css/custom.css"
>

<meta 
    charset="UTF-8"
>
<meta 
    name="viewport" 
    content="width=, initial-scale=1.0"
>
<meta 
    http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" 
    content="ie=edge"
>
<title>
    Pizza World
</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav 
    class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light"
>
    <a 
        class="navbar-brand" 
        href="#"
    >
        Pizza World
    </a>
    <button 
        class="navbar-toggler" 
        type="button" 
        data-toggle="collapse" 
        data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" 
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" 
        aria-expanded="false" 
        aria-label="Toggle navigation"
    >
    <span 
        class="navbar-toggler-icon"
    >
    </span>
    </button>
<div 
        class="collapse navbar-collapse" 
        id="navbarSupportedContent"
>
    <ul 
        class="navbar-nav mr-auto"
    >
        <li 
            class="nav-item active"
        >
        <a 
            class="nav-link" 
            href="#"
        >
            Order Online 
        <span 
            class="sr-only"
        >
            (current)
        </span>
        </a>
        </li>
        <li 
            class="nav-item"
        >
        <a 
            class="nav-link" 
            href="#"
        >
            Menu
        </a>
        </li>
<form 
    class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0"
>
    <input 
        class="form-control mr-sm-2" 
        type="search" 
        placeholder="Zip Code" 
        aria-label="Zip Code"
    >
    <button 
        class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" 
        type="submit"
    >
        Search stores near you!
    </button>
</form>
</div>
</nav>
<div 
    class="jumbotron"
>
        <h1 
            class="display-12 myh1class"
        >
            Hello, world!
        </h1>
        <p 
            class="lead"
        >
            This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.
        </p>
        <hr 
            class="my-4"
        >
        <p>
                It uses utility classes for typography and spacing to space content out within the larger container.
        </p>
        <p 
        class="lead"
        >
          <a 
            class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" 
            href="#" 
            role="button"
        >
            Learn more
        </a>
        </p>
      </div>
<script             
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" i
    ntegrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"
>
</script>
<script 
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"
>
</script>
<script 
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"
>
</script>

    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems the jumbotron bgimg CSS style is applying/loading, but the image isn't resolving.  Check the path?

Comment: Are you referring to the path of the image? If so, yes it's in the correct location. I've even tried adding an id ontp of the element class to try and specifically target it, but still no luck. Not sure if you can view this, but the pizza is inside my img folder as it should be I believe https://puu.sh/C1bqS/6647f966f0.png

Comment: Replacing the img URL in your snippet with a valid image results in the title BG showing: https://imgur.com/a/IC6Yfl8 ... Could be a permissions issue?

Comment: You are trying to add the background to the jumbotron? or the title of the jumbotron?

Comment: @circusdei I even tried adding a url into the background image like you're doing, however still no luck. .jumbotron h1
{
    background-image: url(https://puu.sh/C1c9A/a8ed4b2c26.png)
    !important;
}

I really am starting to think it's just not being linked correctly to my stylesheet, i'll  look into this more now

Comment: that will require the protocl (http/https) then should work

Comment: @circusdei Yes, I did, I just think stackoverflow took it out. https://puu.sh/C1cmz/b1c715b57f.png

Comment: I messed around with changing out the local image for a url, and changed the file path of the custom.css and I finally got the image to appear, however still no luck with a local image, so I will do some more digging and troubleshooting for that, thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear there's progress.  GL.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to override the Bootstrap CSS in a number of ways.

1. You can use !important, as you have here, although it is not really the best way as it can cause unintended behavior later on.
2. You download the Bootstrap JS and CSS files and modify as needed (as opposed to using a CDN link in your headers) and include it in your project files.
3. You can use a CSS selector such as id="bootstrap-override" in your HTML.  Bootstrap mostly uses classes which carry a weight 1/10th of that of an ID.  Here is a good article that explains [CSS Specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

Answer (score 0):

The CSS is at external link and its first reading it, easiest way is to upload Bootstrap CSS to your work files and link it in html, after that just edit it as you want. Pretty easy.